# What is the difference, if any, between 即使 and 無論？

Tags: grammar, usage

Is there a big difference between 即使 and 無論?

I was working on a couple of fill-in-the-blanks exercises and the following sentence came up:

> 你的畫很有特色，_______ 是畫家也不一定能畫得比你好。

I think the right answer here is 即使, but I am not sure why 無論 would not be right. If I did use 無論 would that change the meaning of the sentence, or do the two words mean about the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have different meanings.

即使 is the correct word in this case because it means "even if" or "in fact".

無論 means "regardless" (as does 不管) and would be used in a sentence like 無論是誰畫的，etc. (regardless of who painted it, etc.).